# Proper onDestroy() How to avoid memory leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I read a number of articles on how to avoid memory-leaks in Android, but i'm still not quite sure if I got it right.

I don't have any private or static members(there are only 3 strings) in that Activity, all code is started from within onCreate().

I recycle all of my Bitmaps.

I even try setting as many variables to null if possible and as much as possible

Still i don't recover any  memory after the activity is destroyed

Here is the activity

http://pastie.org/9361167

Comment: are you using Memory Analyzer(MAT)?

Comment: i tried couldn't understand much out of it,just came to know that some byte type is using a lot of memory